# Change shipping costs based on magento grand total- Magento 1.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

- Rs 75/- shipping for all items under 500
- Rs 150 shipping for 1000 and below
- Rs 200 for all items Rs 3000 /- and below
- Rs 250 for Rs 5000 and below
- Rs 350 for all above 5000 /-

Comment: you can use Table rate shipping method

Answer (score 2):

Configuring table rate shipping
You set table rate shipping inside the System menu accessed via Magento’s backend.

While logged in as admin, navigate to System > Configuration and then, in the left menu under Sales, select Shipping Methods.
[image]

That should bring up the table rates menu in the window to the right.
[image]

The first thing to do is to enable table rates by selecting Yes in the drop-down menu for the Enabled option. This will turn off flat rate shipping and allow you to specify different rates based on your chosen criteria.

The next two options, Title and Method Name, allow you to create different table rate shipping policies that you can then select from. For this tutorial, we’ll leave the names as Standard Shipping and Standard.

The next option determines how you want to calculate the shipping. In our example, we’ll be using price vs. destination, so go ahead and select this in the drop-down options.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use Table rate shipping method , there is an option to configure shipping prices according to Total cart price.